# Robot Framework Collections.Remove Values From List removes all values

Tags: robotframework

I am spliting some output into a list, then I am trying to clean the list since there are some values I do not need on the list. I want to remove any list item that is not a node or a date; however, the Remove Values From List keyword returns an empty list. Any sugestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
Create And Clean Times List   
    @{times}    Split String    ${output}       separator=${\n}
    Log List    ${times}
    ${value}=   Set Variable     @{times}[0]
    @{times2}=  Remove Values From List    ${value}
    Log List    ${times2}
```

> >

```
KEYWORD Collections . Log List ${times}
Start / End / Elapsed:  20181012 12:16:32.635 / 20181012 12:16:32.636 / 
00:00:00.001
12:16:32.636    INFO    List length is 28 and it contains following items:
0: META: ran handlers
1: node1 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
2: Fri Oct 12 16:16:29 GMT 2018
3: node2 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
4: Fri Oct 12 16:16:29 GMT 2018
5: node3 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
6: Fri Oct 12 16:16:29 GMT 2018
7: node4 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
8: Fri Oct 12 16:16:29 GMT 2018
9: node5 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
10: Fri Oct 12 16:16:29 GMT 2018
11: node6 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
12: Fri Oct 12 16:16:30 GMT 2018
13: node7 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
14: Fri Oct 12 16:16:31 GMT 2018
15: node8 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
16: Fri Oct 12 16:16:31 GMT 2018
17: node9 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
18: Fri Oct 12 16:16:31 GMT 2018
19: node10 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
20: Fri Oct 12 16:16:31 GMT 2018
21: node11 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
22: Fri Oct 12 16:16:31 GMT 2018
23: node12 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
24: Fri Oct 12 16:16:32 GMT 2018
25: META: ran handlers
26: META: ran handlers
27: [sysadmin@basebox ~]$   

00:00:00.001KEYWORD ${value} = BuiltIn . Set Variable @{times}[0]
Start / End / Elapsed:  20181012 12:16:32.637 / 20181012 12:16:32.638 / 00:00:00.001
12:16:32.638    INFO    ${value} = META: ran handlers
00:00:00.001KEYWORD @{times2} = Collections . Remove Values From List value='${value}'
Documentation:  
Removes all occurrences of given values from list.

Start / End / Elapsed:  20181012 12:16:32.639 / 20181012 12:16:32.640 / 00:00:00.001
12:16:32.640    INFO    @{times2} = [ ] 

Start / End / Elapsed:  20181012 12:16:32.640 / 20181012 12:16:32.641 / 00:00:00.001
00:00:00.001KEYWORD Collections . Log List ${times2}
Documentation:  
Logs the length and contents of the list using given level.

Start / End / Elapsed:  20181012 12:16:32.642 / 20181012 12:16:32.643 / 00:00:00.001
12:16:32.643    INFO    List is empty.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Remove values from list` doesn't return a new list, it removes values from the original list.

Here is a test that illustrates that:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Collections

*** Variables ***
@{full_list}   one  two  three
@{short_list}  one  three

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    ${result}=  remove values from list  ${full_list}  two
    should be equal  ${result}  ${NONE}
    should be equal  ${full_list}  ${short_list}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! the recommended steps worked perfectly.